# In playwright I used codegen to generate code, to test a login page, I copied the code to visual studio, and ran the code in powershell. But it isn't

Tags: .net, visual-studio, playwright, codegen

I was practicing with playwright, I need to test a login page, using powershell I installed playwright, I'm using dotnet 7, visual studio 2022, I used codegen and generated code by recording in the Inspector. I copied the code and pasted in the code file and ran it via powershell command "dotnet test". But it is showing something like this -

"

```
Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
D:\PlaywrightTests\UnitTest1.cs(7,30): warning CS8892: Method 'Program.Main()' will not be used as an entry point becau
se a synchronous entry point 'AutoGeneratedProgram.Main(string[])' was found. [D:\PlaywrightTests\PlaywrightTests.cspro
j]
  PlaywrightTests -> D:\PlaywrightTests\bin\Debug\net7.0\PlaywrightTests.dll
Test run for D:\PlaywrightTests\bin\Debug\net7.0\PlaywrightTests.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.5.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
No test is available in D:\PlaywrightTests\bin\Debug\net7.0\PlaywrightTests.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
```

"

I have provided the code, in that i have added "PRIVATE" instead of true values.

```
using Microsoft.Playwright;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
        await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = false,
        });
        var context = await browser.NewContextAsync();

        var page = await context.NewPageAsync();

        await page.GotoAsync("PRIVATE");

        await page.GetByLabel("Username").ClickAsync();

        await page.GetByLabel("Username").FillAsync("PRIVATE");

        await page.GetByLabel("Password").ClickAsync();

        await page.GetByLabel("Password").FillAsync("PRIVATE");

        await page.GetByRole(AriaRole.Button, new() { Name = "Sign In" }).ClickAsync();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some test annotations.

> You can choose to use NUnit base classes or MSTest base classes that
> Playwright provides to write end-to-end tests. https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro

Have a look at some examples in the screenshots from the [Playwright Test generator documentation](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/codegen#emulate-devices). You see them using `[TestClass]`, some inheretance to this class from `PageTest` and then the `[TestMethod]` annotation above the method..

[image]